# using composition to access values of two different variables?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a class A having textFieldA and class B having textFieldB.

I want to access values of textFieldA and textFieldB into class C and wants to show in label.

If I use composition, how can i access these values or any other?
    Well this is my classA -

```
(IBAction)buttonPress:(id)sender
{ NSUserDefaults *defaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
 [defaults setObject:field1.text forKey:@"field1Key"]; 
[defaults setObject:field2.text forKey:@"field2Key" ]; 
[defaults setObject:field3.text forKey:@"field3Key"]; 
[defaults synchronize]; 
ConfirmController *conf=[[ConfirmController alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
 // corfim=[[ConfirmController alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil]; 
[self.navigationController pushViewController:conf animated:YES ]; 
[conf release]; 
}



This is classB:-- -
(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{ 
label.text=massage; currancyLabel.text=massage1; 
[super viewWillAppear:animated]; 
outputRate.text=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"outputRateKey"];
 float x= [amount.text floatValue]*[massage floatValue]; 
outputRate.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", x]; 
}
```

i want to show these classes textFields in class C
ConfirmController class is classC, formController is classA, currancyController is classB

Comment: How do you create Class A and Class B and Class C

Comment: these classes are in hierarchy with other classes. I have my full fledged project. but i have issue with these three classes. My project is like there will be table view containing different rows. after selecting each row it will take you corrosponding view (classes). But The whole scenario is the same as i explained in simple form

Comment: See the point you are not getting here is , You can have a class as a member variable. But it does not mean that its an object. So Class C can have both Class A and Class B as members but untill you allocate memory its of no use.

Comment: I agree with your point. in classC i have created objects of both classes like classA *objA, classB *objB. and then tried to access textFieldA like labelC=objA.textFieldA.text

Comment: When you declare in class C they are not objects yet. These are just members. When you allocate classC then you create first object. Now you can access classA obj using the dot(.) notation.

Comment: ClassC *objc = [[ClassC alloc] init]. Then you can access ClassA with objc.objA but you have to then allocate it also. So basically you are little confused. I am out of votes today else i could have upvoted a few well composed question so that we could start a chat on this.

Comment: Ya actually i dont have much points to chat.So you mean after allocating classC and objc.objA *ob=[[obc.objA alloc]init]; then i can access textFieldA like. ob.textFieldA?

Comment: objc.objA = [[ClassA alloc] init]; objc.objA.textfieldA is the way you can access textfieldA but untill you allocate or have a synthesize and outlet you will have to allocate the textfield too.

Comment: in classC.h i did @class classA, classB and in classC.m i did #import classA, classB. Is this all i have to import

Comment: and i can access textFieldA like objA.textFieldA?

Comment: I am trying this. Thanku so much your time anyways

Comment: Yes but i am not sure if you understood.

Comment: Ok drop a comment if you don't get it. I will write a blog post may be explaining it.

Comment: I think obc.objA=[[ClassA alloc]init]; is wrong. i have tried all you suggested. didn;t succeed.Please i will really appreciate if you will make a blog post and let me know.i am really struglling

Comment: @praveen S. -If you get time can you please help me to sort it out. Because i have tried all things. not working. Can you make a blog post if possible

Comment: Why don't you post some code here. Remove the unnecessary things and paste the skeleton code. And also what you want to do with Class C. How is textfield in class a and b filled?

Comment: Well this is my classA  -(IBAction)buttonPress:(id)sender{

 NSUserDefaults *defaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
 [defaults setObject:field1.text forKey:@"field1Key"];
 [defaults setObject:field2.text forKey:@"field2Key" ];
 [defaults setObject:field3.text forKey:@"field3Key"];
 
 
 

 [defaults synchronize];
 ConfirmController *conf=[[ConfirmController alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
  //  corfim=[[ConfirmController alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:conf animated:YES ];

 [conf release];
}

Comment: Add it to question with formatting

Comment: This is classB:-- -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

    
 
    
     label.text=massage;
    currancyLabel.text=massage1;
       [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    
   
    outputRate.text=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"outputRateKey"];    
    float  x= [amount.text floatValue]*[massage floatValue];
 outputRate.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", x];
    
}

Comment: i want to show these classes textFields in class C

Comment: ConfirmController class is classC, formController is classA, currancyController is classB

Comment: Yup i got that, add these comments to the question and format it, so that its readable.

Comment: Never mind, i will format this myself.

Comment: i tried it to format . i couldnot succeed. sorry. hope im clear in my explanation. i.e. this is the code you need to understand what i am trying to do

Comment: Where are you creating these controllers? You should be creating them and adding them to some view rite. Where is it?

Comment: Yes i have linked xib file with these three classes. i have made textFields on them. and these code are from .m file of corrosponding classA and classB

Comment: Where do you add the view from classA and classB in your app

Comment: This is classC , i want to add view from classA and classB to classC:-- - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated   {[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"ConfirmController" owner:self options:nil ];   
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
 }

Comment: if you want to explain me i can call you. if you dont mind

Comment: I will update this thread after an hour or so.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you mean for "composition". Anyway if in your class "C" you initialize two instances:

```
A *a;
B *b;
```

then you can access the two text values using:

```
NSString *textA = a.textFieldA.text;
NSString *textB = b.textFieldB.text;
```

Comment: I did the same thing. Problem is classC is subclass of classA. like in class C, classC.h says: @interface classC : classA {...} when i run it shows no error but not showing as well. I think problem is with importing files . like #import etc. in classC.h i have imported both classes A and B. for example #import "classA.h" #import "classB.h"

Comment: if you have no compilation errors importing is ok. #import doesn't instantiate classes, you must do it manually in classC and there is no problem in classC to instantiate a classA instance. Posting your code will probably help.

Answer (score 0):

Step1: Create an object for both class A and B lets say objA and ObjB

Step2: Create a property textFieldA and textFieldB respectively for class A and class B

Step3: Create a label in your class C lets say labelC

Step4: Now access the value of text field

```
NSString* msgA = objA.textFieldA.text
NSString* msgB = objB.textFieldB.text
```

Step5:

```
labelC.text = [msgA stringByAppendingString:msgB];
```

Comment: I did the same thing. Problem is classC is subclass of classA. like in class C, classC.h says:    @interface classC : classA        {...} when i run it shows no error but not showing as well.  I think problem  is with importing files . like #import etc. in classC.h i have imported both classes A and B. for example #import "classA.h"  #import "classB.h"

Comment: you need to #import the file, but you can do that in your implementation file (.m), and use the @class declaration in your header file.

Comment: these two things i will do but in which class? in classC?

Comment: it does not show values of textFieldA and textFieldB in labelC

Comment: actually my code is complex. i explained it in simple way above. But just wondering my class C would be subclass of? like in classC.h file @interface classC: uiviewController{...}. i think problem is with importing files

Comment: If it is not urgent, can i look at tomorrow or else give me the time i will write the code tomorrow and give it to you. :)

Comment: in my classC.h i imported other two classes like @class classA, classB... and in classC.m i use #import classA, classB... is it ok

Comment: No problem. I will really greatfull to you because i have taken it as my first professional project and really serious about it. God Bless You. you can do it tomorrow. Thanks

Comment: have you get time to look at my problem. if u have then i really thankful to u